# C#: Reflection to insert items into generic list

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to add an object created by reflection into a generic list. At compile time I don't know the exact type of this object or the type of generic list, but I can make sure the type matches.

I found a lot of posts talking about similar issue but they either don't require a generic list or the type is known at compile time.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

If `l` is your generic list, and `o` is your object:

```
l.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(l, new object[] { o });
```

Per suggestion of **jgauffin**, you can perform the following test to make sure you can add the object to the list:

```
if (l.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType()))
{
    l.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(l, new object[] { o });
}
```

Comment: +1. you can also show how he can use `type.GetGenericArguments()` and `type.IsAssignableFrom()` to check that the object is of the correct type first.

Comment: Is it possible to implement ForEach method using this approach? And if yes, how can we pass an Action to the foreach to be executed?

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari Yes, you can do this exactly as the sample above for `Add` method, provided you have an `Action<T>` delegate with compatible type.

Answer (score 0):

use SomeObject.GetType() to get its type:

```
  MyClass t1 = new MyClass();
  Type t = t1.GetType();
```